# New variable for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

My problem is that I don't know how to create new variables using a for-loop.

Let's assume to have a matrix named X

```
x1 x2 x3
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

what I want to get is (it's easy but it's just an example)

```
v1=1
v2=5
v3=9
```

I want to use a for-loop like this one:

```
for (i in 1:3){
  v_i=X[i,i]
 }
```

But it doesn't work because I don't know how to create a new variable using the "i" index (v1,v2,v3,...).

Comment: Maybe it was just this toy example, but it looks like you want to access the diagonal of the matrix. This can be done more efficiently than with a loop using `diag(X)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `assign` for this.

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  assign(sprintf("X_%s", i), i)
}

> ls()
[1] "i"   "X_1" "X_2" "X_3"
```

But I would be willing to bet my families farm that this is probably not what you're really after. A lot of things can be solved using a list, which come with already made tools to handle them (like `lapply`, `sapply`...).

Answer (score 0):

For loops execute in the global environment (functions create their own), So you need to make an object for the loop to update

```
MyNewX <- vector(mode="numeric",length=3)
```

Then have the loop update this object

```
for (i in 1:3){
  MyNewX[i] <- X[i,i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming X is your dataframe name

```
for (i in 1:3) {
      assign(eval(paste0("v", i)), X[i,i])
   }
```